# Parsing a map from XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Here is my xml

```
  <body>
      <map>
         <key1>
            value1
         </key1>
         <key2>
            value2
         </key2>
         ....
      </map>
  <body>
```

And i have:

```
Document xPacket;
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Map<Integer, String> temp = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Object rawMap = xPath.compile("//body/map/").evaluate(xPacket, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList mapNodeList = (NodeList) rawMap;
```

but how to iterate through `NodeList` and fill values in map?

Comment: Does NodeList have any methods?  What are they?  Anything like a method to get name, attributes or child nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't specify otherwise, I'm assuming you are using classes of the standard Java library.

The [`NodeList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) object has an `item(int)` method. You can use that method to loop through the nodes in the `NodeList`:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap();
for (int i = 0; i < aNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node item = aNodeList.item(i);
    map.put(Integer.valueOf(item.getTextContent()), item.getLocalName());
}
```

Here I assumed that you wish to map the text content of the XML key nodes to the nodes' names (because of the type parameters of your map).